# Stan constraints on inverse logit

Tags: model, multinomial-distribution, stan

There are four mutually exclusive events I want to model - or rather, three events and their absence. The three events' rate of occurrence together is very small, with a 99% chance none of them will occur. So I would model them with a multinomial. So far so good.

However, I know that the rate of occurrence of the $i^{\text{th}}$ event is given by $\theta_i=\text{inv.logit}(A_i + B_i)$, where $-\infty<A_i<+\infty$ and $0\leq B_i<+\infty$, and I have priors on these $A_i$ and $B_i$, which are the quantities I am actually interested in modelling. Therefore, the parametres of the multinomial are transformed parametres.

But for the sampling to work, I need to constrain the $A_i$ and $B_i$ somehow, so as to make $\sum_{i=1}^3 \theta_i < 1$. Just constraining the transformed parametres doesn't seem to work, and it fails to sample. Is there a way to do it? I tried constraining $A_i$ to $\leq-2$ but that is rather ad hoc and not the true constraint, and will not always work.

--EDIT:

For clarification, I'm actually modelling the $\theta_i$ over time and fitting them to a decreasing function, and $A_i + B_i$ is the value $\theta_i$ takes at t=0, so the problem isn't as underspecified as it looks. I just need to figure out how to constrain the parametres, the other things are (for now) taken care of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's an obvious way to do it which works fairly well for my purposes, which is doing something like this:

```
parameters {
    simplex [4] T;
    vector <lower = 0> [4] B;
}

transformed parameters {
    vector [4] A = logit (T) - B;
}
```

I have to modify the model priors and mess with the Jacobian for this to work but it's doable.